# Making a snake game. I'm not able to change the screen after movement detected. C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm sorry for my humble translation of my code. I'm not native English so I don't have a plain ideea how it is translated into English. What I'm trying to do is a snake game in C++. First of all I want to know how to get to move the character(an '=') around the map. I tried this and I managed to get a hand of the movement and I'm pretty sure I'll be using it for the whole game. So the game starts by giving a value to n which represents the number of columns and rows of the matrix. After that, I'll be showing the matrix so the player has an ideea how it looks like but, after a key is pressed I have to show the new matrix and the old one will also be shown upside of it so, in the end I'll be having a screen filled with matrix. I want to replace the old matrix with the new matrix after the movement key is pressed. How can I do so? This is my curent code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[100][100];
    unsigned i, j, k, punct, n, m, x, y;
    int c;
    cout << "The game is represented by a matrix of n rows and n columns. Give a value to 'n'";
    cin >> n;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            a[i][j] = ' '; // I'm creating the matrix and I'm filling it with empty spaces.
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) //Now I'm creating the border lines.
        {
            a[1][j] = '/';
            a[i - 1][1] = '/';
            a[n][j] = '/';
            a[i - 1][n] = '/';
            a[3][3] = '=';
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) //I'm showing the matrix.
            cout << a[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }
    while (1)    //Infinite loop.
    {
        x = 3;
        y = 3;
        if (kbhit())  //I'm checking if a key is pressed.
        {
            c = getch();
            if (c == 72)  //If a key is pressed make the character which is represented by a '=' to move upward by a space.
            {
                x = x - 1;
                y = y - 0;
                a[x][y] = '=';
                a[x + 1][y] = ' ';

            }
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) //Again I'm showing the matrix in order to see the difference and where the character has moved.
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                    cout << a[i][j];
                cout << endl;
            }

        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code formatting is a nightmare.

Comment: I'm aware of that, sorry mate ~__~.

Comment: But fixing it would have required less than a minute. Would have been nice if you had put in that effort, instead of someone else trying to uphold the site's standards.

Comment: @Therainmaker, then I think I misunderstood what he was saying. What would you want me to change into my code? Please tell me and I'll gladly do so! I thought he said that it is not effecient enough and that I'm using too many comands and lines. What else was he reffering to? Of course, I would like to make your job as easy as possible, even if it would took me some extra time. I'm kind of a newbie here, sorry.

Comment: All he meant was that your initial question had a lot of unnecessary indentation and empty lines. If you look at the code you posted, and the edited code, the only difference is that it is now more readable and removes unnecessary blank spaces. Indentation is good, but you had done too much of it. He didn't mean using too many commands.

Comment: @therainmaker, ohh, I got it. Thank you for your feedback, I'm gladly accepting it. It won't repeat again. Sorry that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your question**: Since you are already using conio.h, use `clrscr()` or `system("cls")`. But please don't use conio.h.

**For your code**: You need to organize it better. Separate different tasks you program has to do in different functions. For a game, specifically, try to separate your game logic from its presentation on the screen, and you will have an easier time reasoning about it(and maybe you would have discovered that your matrix is simply not need). I took the liberty of adjusting a little(actually a lot, really) of your code.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool update(unsigned& x, unsigned& y, unsigned n) {
  if (kbhit()) {  //I'm checking if a key is pressed.
    switch (getch()) { // get real value for the arrow
    case 75:
      y--;
      if (y==1) y++; // Cancel if in wall;
      break;
    case 77:
      y++;
      if (y==n) y--; // Cancel if in wall;
      break;
    case 80:
      x++;
      if (x==n) x--; // Cancel if in wall;
      break;
    case 72:
      x--;
      if (x==1) x++; // Cancel if in wall;
      break;
    case 27: // ESC to quit
      return true; // exit
    }
  }
  return false; // Do not exit, continue the game.
}

void draw(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned n) {
  // MAYBE your conio.h has clrscr(). Mine doesn't. So I use system.
  system("cls"); // clear screen before drawing. WILL PRODUCE FLICKERING. A LOT.
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
      // No need for a matrix for drawing, you can infer each character quite
      // easily.
      if (i==1 || j==1 || i==n || j==n) {
        putch('/');
      }
      else {
        if (i == x && j == y) {
          putch('=');
        }
        else {
          putch(' ');
        }
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  unsigned n, x, y;
  cout << "The game is represented by a matrix of n rows and n columns. Give a value to 'n': ";
  cin >> n;
  x = 3;
  y = 3;
  bool exit = false;
  while (!exit) { // Don't do an infinite loop. Your user will want an exit.
      exit = update(x,y,n);
      draw(x,y,n);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Since you're using conio.h, I adapted some concepts to use it, but once you get used to the language and programming in general, move away from conio.h and try to find a better presentation/input layer for your programs(including your games), preferably a standard-conforming one. There are plenty of such libraries for C++.

And a tip especially for a snake game: Instead of keeping an (x,y) position, keep a collection of them, for each of your snake's pieces.

Comment: Wow, you've done so much for me right there, thank you kind sir! I'll be using your code as an example and trying to adapt it in my own way. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

What I am able to infer from your question is that you want to display the new matrix and want the older one to be hidden away, as opposed to being placed exactly on top of it. Please correct me if I misunderstood something.

One simple (but not so elegant) way to do this would be to print a hundred empty new lines and then print the next matrix. This will, only the new matrix will be shown. Also, the console would only store a finite amount of lines (generally), and so this isn't even going to keep using up too much space (even if console keeps all lines, I doubt it would be too much).

You could insert `cout << string(100, '\n' );` in your code just before you print the new matrix. This command prints 100 new lines.

A more elegant way (I haven't tested it yet) would be to use the `system(cls)` command to clean the console window. Inserting this command before printing the matrix should also do the trick. However, using system commands in C++ is considered bad practice.

EDIT: Another simple method to overwrite the console output would be to print the backspace character (`cout << '\b'`) the required number of times before printing something again. However, the issue with this is that the cursor only moves back in the buffer of cout. So, if your buffer is flushed, then you cannot move to the text already displayed. Inserting a new line command (`cout << endl`) flushes the buffer, and so would not be applicable in this particular case. Added it here because I thought it would be useful for you to know.

A precise solution to what you are looking for can be found in WinAPI (but this is operating system specific, and so I wouldn't recommend it). You can check out SetConsoleCursorPosition and GetStdHandle function for more information.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. I want to hide the old matrix and replace it with a new one. I'll try this method untill I find a btter one, thank you ^__^.

Comment: I have added some more information to the answer which could be relevant to you. Commenting here so that you can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your shoes I would start from a graphics library/game engine and try to build the game on that. Something like SMFL (http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php).

Getting back to your question, I remember Borland C++ having a library called conio that had functions to clear the screen, put a character at a given coordinate on the console, ... but that was only for DOS I think. GNU has a similar library: ncurses (https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) which is for Linux or similar operating systems. For windows, you can use something similar: PDcurses (http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/).

These libraries hav functions to put a character at a given coordinate, so what you need to do is as simple as initializing the screen first thing when you start the program (which is `initscr()` in ncurses). Then you draw the snake in the coordinate that you want using something similar to `mvaddch(row, col, ch);` which is going to move the cursor to coordinate `(row, col)` and then print the character given by `ch`. Then what a key is pressed, you delete the snakes head in its old position by printing a blank character  in the old positions, and then putting the head in the new position. So, for example:

```
//add this header to include the library, but you need to download and install the library before you can use it
#include <ncurses.h>

//inside the program, let's say in main:
....
//initialize
initscr();

/initial location of snakes head
int row = ..., col = ...;
int oldrow, oldcol;
//game loop
while(...)
{
    oldrow = row;
    oldcol = col;
    ch = getch();
    switch(ch)
    {
         case KEY_RIGHT:
             col++;
             break;
         //rest of game logics
         ...
    }
    mvaddch(oldrow, oldcol, ' ');
    mvaddch(row, col, '=');
    refresh();
}
endwin();
```

obviously, this is not what the snake game is about. In the real game you should change `row` and `col` at every clock tick, and then when a key is pressed you change the direction of movement.

Again, at the end, I'll suggest you choose a graphics library/game engine and work with that instead on working in text mode. It will be easier for you to expand/modify the game later on. And even if you wanted to have a game with a classic feel, you can make the game have a vintage, textual feel to it.